# Is a sequence a subsequence of itself?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

I know that sets are subsets of themselves, so by that logic is that true for sequences?

Comment: not quite by the same logic, but rather by the definition of subsequence: yes, a sequences is a subsequence of itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a sequence is one of its own subsequence, which is similar to an idea that any set is a subset of itself.

If we want to specify that a subsequence is *not* the entire sequence, we refer to it as a *proper* subsequence.  That is, every subsequence except for the sequence itself is a proper subsequence.  In the same vein, a proper subset of a set is a subset not equal to that set.